# Receive emails from multiple accounts using mailman gem in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, mailman-gem

I want to access multiple accounts using mailman gem in rails. Is there a way to open multiple accounts in a single process of mailman in rails 4?

Comment: anyluck in doing this. I'm also stuck with same requirement